# Eclipse - Show layout guides (lines) in the graphical layout for Android views

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am following a tutorial on Android Development, their video shows "layout lines" in the graphical layout. Such as when you place a LinearLayout you can see a light line around it so that it is obvious on screen.

The tutorial shows a button alongside the Zoom buttons above the editor that turns these lines on and off. However I do not have this button in Eclipse (latest version for java devs), I have googled and googled but can not find how to turn this on.

Any ideas?

Comment: to make my question a little clearer here is a screen shot from the tutorial. [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7069923/eclipselayoutlines.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had my question answered on another site, so I will provide the answer here also for anyone who stumbles across this page.

It seems that the feature I was seeking has actually been removed from the more recent (v16 and v17) copies of the ADT. I do not know why as it is actually a useful feature, but ours is not to reason why!

Thank you to those who looked at this question.

Answer (score 0):

It is a functionality of the newer ADTs. Upgrade your Adt to the latest one and you would start seeing this feature.

Comment: I only installed the ADT yesterday, surely google should have provided the newest one from the repositiory!?  But I will give it a try, thank you.

Comment: I have just checked and I have ADT 17.0.0 the latest one on developer.android.com.